# Select2 Tags: Dynamicly add tag to input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

I am looking for a solution to add a tag to the input tag field.

I know it is possible to have preloaded tags, but I have found no way to add a tag to the input. I.e. using a specific function, I could append a selection (with ID and TEXT).

I have searched quite a bit, but maybe I'm in a dead loop. Any suggestions?

This is how I initialize:

```
    $('.select2Input').select2({
        tags: {
            0: {
                id: 'the id',
                text: 'the text'
            }
        },
        multiple: true,
        minimumInputLength: 2
    });
```

Comment: share your code to begin...

Comment: Done. Highly doubt it'll help solve my question though.

Comment: You can doubt, or read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in this related question [select2 destroy and recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898693/set-json-data-from-ajax-and-make-it-serarchable-in-select2-jquery/22928349#22928349), the trick lies in destroying and recreating the select2 when you need to change the initialization options.  i suspect that this is what you need to do in your case as well.

the basic syntax is

```
$('#categoryid').select2("destroy");
createmycategoryidselect();

function createmycategoryidselect() {
   // standard options
   $opts = { ... }
   // gather the current set of tag values and stick them in this new instance.
   $opts.tags = { ... new tags ... }
}
```